# Populating ListView with data stored in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have data stored in SQLite database.
I would like to extract data from this database and show it as list (in `ListView`)
How can I do this?

Comment: this is a tuto for custom listView http://www.tutozone.info/2014/10/tutoriel-listview-personnalisee-avec.html , and this is for sqite http://www.tutozone.info/2014/10/android-sqlite-tutorial.html ,u can use them

Answer (score 1):

SO is a webpage for finding bugs/helping newbies code. What you're asking is how to bind a custom listview (that, presumably) you have built and asking a stranger how to your SQLLites data in it.

Do you see your problem yet with your question?

I suggest reading a couple of tutorials, such as:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

and

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

to get you started.

Come back if your code fails, and if youve made an actual effort.

Paul